# Small Cap for citations in-text

Tags: fonts, biblatex, citing, small-caps

How can I have citations in-text written in small cap?

This is how I load `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,backend=biber,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}
```

I've tried the *option* `scauthors=all` but I receive the error:

```
! Package etoolbox Error: Invalid boolean value 'all'.
```

Comment: `scauthors` is fairly new, it was introduced in v1.9.2 and changed in v1.9.5. What version of `biblatex-philosophy` do you have?

Comment: Just checked with my version of the package (v1.9.6) and it worked great. Note that `scauthors=all` will set *all* names in small caps, if you only want citations, you need `scauthors=cite` or `scauthors=citefn`.

Comment: @moewe How can I check the version?

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document and compile the file (best without `scauthors=all` so that no errors are caused). TeX will then report all used packages and their versions neatly in a list at the end of the `.log` file. Depending on the TeX distribution you use you can also check with the 'Package Manager' (MikTeX) or `tlmgr` (TeX live). Updating works as described in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)

Comment: @moewe Because I've Tex live I've used `tlmgr info biblatex-philosophy` and I've found that I'v the 1.8 version. So I've to upgrade my distribution, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Read the link from my last comment thoroughly. You will probably have to install a newer TeX live (2017).

Comment: @moewe Suppose I install Tl17, then how can I tell Texworks to use the new version? Now in `/usr/local/texlive` I've the folder `2016`. If I see in Texworks `Edit -> Preferences -> Typesetting` I note that  in the section `Path for Tex and related programs` I don't have ``/usr/local/texlive/2016`. Is it ok in your opinion?

Comment: Mhh, I'm not a Unix/Mac OS user. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864. It depends on where you installed the binaries to if the path settings are good or not. Just change all 2016 to 2017 in your settings and check which directory your PATH includes.

Comment: Any news here? Did an update help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to older version of the software that did not support the desired feature. With the current version `scauthors` works as advertised.